# opening mamp mysql in terminal mac

Tags: mysql, terminal, mamp

Im trying to get stuck into MySQL but seem to have fallen at the first hurdle.

Ive got mamp setup and running on my mac, when i go into the terminal and type `mysql` to try and bring up the 'Welcome to the MySQL monitor' intro, i get the follow error :

```
-bash: mysql: command not found
```

I think its due to the fact ive never told it were to find mysql or linked it to mamp, but im not sure if that's correct, is there something else im missing here ? Just to be clear ive opened terminal waited for it to load and type the command, nothing else.

my mamp/mysql folder is located at applications/mamp/db/mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialise it from the proper location. First make sure that you are locating the file from the correct location and then type something along these lines:

```
/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql -uroot -proot
```

Or set up an alias if you want call it by typing just *mysql*.